# Firebase - Apple Search Ads Campaign Result Track

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics

Running Search Ads Campaign, now looking for the result is gives positive or negative impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a amount of research on Google but no success.

Accidentally, found the option in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), it a good huh.. :)

**Go through following steps now**

1. Choose the right project
2. Analytics section -> Select
   project(iOS/Android)
3. Attribution > `ecommerce_purchase` > Source option with dropdown

Please check attached SS for more details[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get this working as well and not seeing my campaigns from the dropdown. Did you need to include the iAd or AdSupport frameworks as well?